# Trying to fetch image from another image server (akamai) in React.js

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, api, akamai

I fetch some data in the Opendota API and I noticed their user images for steam are hosted somewhere else, it is on the akamai server.

here's the path when I print it in the html

`https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ae/aed0b0fa4bed2039628fe5e95b28de608cfe4359.jpg`

here's where I loaded my opendotaAPI for the information about pro players

**Players.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import PlayerInfo from "./PlayerInfo"


const URL = "https://api.opendota.com/api/proPlayers";




class Players extends Component {    
    state = {
        data:[],
        searchTerm: ""
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(URL)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.data
                });
            });

    }
    render(){
        const Filter = this.state.data.filter(name =>`${name.personaname}`.toUpperCase()
        .indexOf(this.state.searchTerm.toUpperCase()) >= 0)
        .map(name => 
            <PlayerInfo
            key = {name.account_id}
            {...name}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
                 Search: <input style={styleInput}
                        onChange={this.handleSearchTerm}
                        value={this.state.searchTerm}
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search player"
                    />
                <div><h1>{Filter}</h1></div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Players;
```

here's my component where i passed the data

**PlayersInfo.js**

```
import React from 'react'


const PlayerInfo = (props) =>(
    <div>
        <img src={"https://api.opendota.com" + props.avatar}/>
        <h1>{props.personaname}</h1>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <br />
    </div>

)


export default PlayerInfo;
```

I also tried to do this method `<img src={"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net" + props.avatar}/>` The results are just broken image and err_name_not_resolved from the console.

did I miss something or do I need to add the API for the akamai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns the full path to the image in the `avatar` property.

Trying replacing

`<img src={"https://api.opendota.com" + props.avatar}/>`

with

`<img src={props.avatar}/>`